# Specman e compilation error: No such variable 'XXX'

Tags: specman, e

I define a variable `my_reg_file` in function `post_access()` (this function is a `vr_ad` hook for implementing side effects):

```
//file1.e
extend TIMER_LOAD_0 vr_ad_reg {
    post_access(direction : vr_ad_rw_t) is first {
        var my_reg_file : TIMER vr_ad_reg_file = 
        get_parents()[0].as_a(TIMER vr_ad_reg_file);

        ....  

    };
};
```

Then I extend this function in another e file:

```
//file2.e
extend TIMER_LOAD_0 vr_ad_reg {
    post_access(direction : vr_ad_rw_t) is also {
        start my_reg_file.some_tcm();
    };
};
```

I get a compilation error:

```
*** Error: No such variable 'my_reg_file'
```

Why `post_access()` does not recognizes the variable `my_reg_file`? Thank you for your help.

Note: file1.e is imported before file2.e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my_reg_file is a local variable, of that specific method layer, and is not shared with other method layers.
I think the only way to communicate between method layers are: 
a. using the result saved variable which can be accessed from any method layer.
b. using a struct member.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, which seems even better, is to add a separate method to this subtype, e.g. `get_my_reg_file()`, which will return the desired value, and then call this method where this value is needed, instead of using the local variable.